# How do I use static constant variables as inputs to lists in Spring IOC

Tags: ioc-container, spring.net

Here's what I need to do.....

I've got a list of required dependent services. For the sake of example, lets call them ServiceA, ServiceB and ServiceC. I need to be able to define any permutation of those services in my spring configuration file. So for instance I could have

```xml
<constructor-arg name="requiredServices">
  <list element-type="string">
    <value>ServiceA</value>
    <value>ServiceB</value>
  </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

This would indicate that I need services A and B. My problem is, that I'm using local strings in the Spring file to reference ServiceA and ServiceB, when I would much rather use the system wide constant names for ServiceA and ServiceB. So I guess what I'd like to see is

```xml
<constructor-arg name="requiredServices">
  <list element-type="string">
    <value>MyStringConstantsFile.ServiceA</value>
    <value>MyStringConstantsFile.ServiceB</value>
  </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

Then, if we ever rename ServiceA, the spring.config file will still operate properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a bit of banging, but I got what I needed. You need to solve the problem in two steps.

First, add an entry to your spring config file for every constant you'd like to use. Mine looks like this

```xml
<object id="serverAName"
        type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.FieldRetrievingFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
  <property name="TargetType" value="CoreNamespace.ConstantsClass, CoreLibrary"/>
  <property name="TargetField" value="ServerAName"/>
</object>
```

So in an assembly called `CoreLibrary`, I have a class called `ConstantsClass` that exists in namespace `CoreNamespace`.

Then, if I want to use this constant as an input to a list I simply add the following line to the spring config file

```xml
<property name="RequiredComponents">
  <list element-type="string">
    <ref object="serverAName"/>
  </list>
</property>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a [Spring expression](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html), your configuration can look like this:

```xml
<object id="myObject" type="q6932134.ServiceClient, q6932134">
  <constructor-arg name="requiredServices">
    <list element-type="string">
      <expression value="MyConstants.ServiceA" />
      <expression value="MyConstants.ServiceB" />
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

This comes pretty close to desired configuration in your question :-)

For this to work, you do have to register your `MyConstants` type with spring; put the following code somewhere in your main routine:

```cs
TypeRegistry.RegisterType("MyConstants", typeof(MyConstants));
```

The following alternative configuration allows you to use an object reference, much the same as in your own answer. This makes the configuration  more verbose, but has the advantage that your configuration files become less sensitive to renaming your constants in code:

```xml
  <object id="svca" type="string">
    <constructor-arg expression="MyConstants.ServiceA" />
  </object>
  <object id="svcb" type="string">
    <constructor-arg expression="MyConstants.ServiceB" />
  </object>

  <object id="myObject" type="q6932134.ServiceClient, q6932134">
    <constructor-arg name="requiredServices">
      <list element-type="string">
        <ref object="svca" />
        <ref object="svcb" />
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
  </object>
```

If you don't like to register your `MyConstants` programmatically, you can change the expression as follows:

```xml
<constructor-arg expression="T(MyNamespace.MyConstants).ServiceA" />
```

Comment: thanks for tip but those who are in the unfortunate scenario make sure you put the SPeL delimiters in your invocation: <constructor-arg value="#{T(MyNamespace.MyConstants).ServiceA}" />

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  if spring supports that out of the box, but you could read those with reflection in the code of the object you are constructing.

Or create a parser like helper and instead of assigning a list of strings you could assign a list of those references, although the xml definition will more verbose than it is now.

hth